# Error during uninstall of OpenCV 3.2.0 from Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: opencv

I want to upgrade OpenCV from 3.2.0 to 3.4.3 from my Ubuntu 16.04 machine. I'm trying to remove OpenCV 3.2.0 as a first step (otherwise I guess installing another version in parallel would be a bad idea?). Since I installed from source, I went to the build directory and executed `sudo make uninstall`. After a short time, the procedure fails with

```
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/nettef/opencv-3.2.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/nettef/opencv-3.2.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Makefile:10212: recipe for target 'cmake_check_build_system' failed
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
```

The error log entries read (first one, but the others are similar):

```
Build output check failed:
    Regex: 'command line option .* is valid for .* but not for C\+\+'
    Output line: 'cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wmissing-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++'
Compilation failed:
    source file: '/home/nettef/opencv-3.2.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx'
    check option: ' -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations  -Wmissing-prototypes'
===== BUILD LOG =====
Change Dir: /home/nettef/opencv-3.2.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTC_5ef6c/fast"
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_5ef6c.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_5ef6c.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/nettef/opencv-3.2.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_5ef6c.dir/src.cxx.o
/usr/bin/c++     -O3 -DNDEBUG   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_5ef6c.dir/src.cxx.o -c /home/nettef/opencv-3.2.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wmissing-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
/home/nettef/opencv-3.2.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx:1:0: warning: ignoring #pragma   [-Wunknown-pragmas]
 #pragma
 ^
Linking CXX executable cmTC_5ef6c
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_5ef6c.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++     -O3 -DNDEBUG    CMakeFiles/cmTC_5ef6c.dir/src.cxx.o  -o cmTC_5ef6c -rdynamic 
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/nettef/opencv-3.2.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'

===== END =====
```

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/9493), I tried commenting out the line with `-Wmissing-prototypes` but there was no effect.

Answer (score 3):

The error is indicating that cmake could not find the `modules` folder from the `opencv_contrib` directory. Make sure you are pointing to the correct path.

```
-D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib-3.4.3/modules
```

Comment: Thanks, it solved the problem.